# Not sure how to solve this 'memory error'

Tags: python

I am currently getting a memory whenever I run my code. Here is the section of my code that is causing the problem. The line clear_nodes.append(i+(grid_size*4)) is the one which gives the memory error and i'm not sure how to get rid of it. Thanks

```
blocked_rows = []
for num in range(grid_size, 2*grid_size):
    blocked_rows.append(num)
    blocked_rows.append(num+(grid_size*2))
    blocked_rows.append(num+2*(grid_size*2))
    blocked_rows.append(num+3*(grid_size*2))
    blocked_rows.append(num+4*(grid_size*2))
    blocked_rows.sort()
    clear_nodes = []
    for i in blocked_rows:
        if i == (grid_size*2)-1:
            clear_nodes.append(i)
        if i == (grid_size*3):
            clear_nodes.append(i)
        for i in clear_nodes:
            clear_nodes.append(i+(grid_size*4))
            #clear_nodes.append(i+(grid_size*8))
        for i in clear_nodes:
            if i < (grid_size * grid_size):
                all_blocked.append(i)
```

Comment: `for i in clear_nodes:  clear_nodes.append(...)` is an infinite loop - you're adding elements to the list you're iterating over.  If you only want to iterate over the elements that were already present, you need to use a copy of the list: `for i in clear_nodes[:]:`.

Comment: That seems a N * N * N complexity due to the three nested "for"; I think you shouls refactor your code

Comment: You should post the exact error message that your code spits out, it will give us many hints

Comment: Thanks Jason :) great help

Comment: A more elegant way to get what you want with the loop: `clear_nodes.extend(i + grid_size * 4 for i in clear_nodes)`.